# How can I get the label text from an input field in serialization?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I want to serialize all input from #form-unique, including the label.text. How can I extract the label text in this case?

I have following HTML which is part of form form-unique.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="moneyNeeded" id="moneyYes" value="1" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="moneyYes">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="moneyNeeded" id="moneyNo" value="0">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="moneyNo">No</label>
</div>
```

The jQuery looks like this:

```
var model = {};
    $.each($('#form-unique').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        model[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

The output I keep getting is 1 or 0, but I want Yes or No.

Comment: You’d have to do the mapping manually, or stop using a value you don’t actually want as its value.

Comment: @DaveNewton I use the value for a sum. So if totalValue > 3, something happens. Else, something happens. In this case I only have 5 different types. How would I map this manually?

Comment: Or you could count the number of “yes”s, which seems closer to the intent. Or convert on the server side.

Comment: @DaveNewton They are all different questions, not always yes/no. I have 2 yes/no's, and they have different values(first yes 0, second yes 1).

Answer (score 0):

I did the changes necessary to make it work and got this:

```
var model = [];

$('.form-check input').each(function(){
  model.push({
    name: $(this).parent().find('label').text(),
    value: $(this).val()
  })
})
```

result:

```
[{
  name: "Yes",
  value: "1"
},{
  name: "No",
  value: "0"
}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it in this simple way

- Use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to `"Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements."`
- Use [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to `"Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements"`

```js
$(".form-check-input").on("change", function(){
        var model = {};
        $(".form-check-input").each((_,field) => {
             var $field = $(field);
             model[$field.next().text()] = $field.val();
        });
        console.log(model);
        console.log("Checked: " + $(".form-check-input:checked").next().text());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="moneyNeeded" id="moneyYes" value="1" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="moneyYes">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="moneyNeeded" id="moneyNo" value="0">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="moneyNo">No</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: How can I get the value of the input with this code?

Comment: `model[$field.next().text()] = $field.val()`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please have a look at @Some Name